# How to block volume button even when my app is not running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-event

I want to block the volume button even when my app is not running how to do it..?

Comment: Please don't do this. I prefer to have my volume buttons fully functional.

Comment: I just want to do this only at a particular time.. my problem is volume buttons are blocked in my app but if the keypad is locked and suddenly when my app come no key pad is not open still so u can cut the volume so during this time i must disapble the button so only can u help me..

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. The Volume Buttons can't be monitored or accessed by your app unless it is the current foreground app (i.e. you have an Activity visible and in use on the screen).